# What is the R function `c( )` coercing when inputs are numeric and bigq?

Tags: r, gmp

Consider these two contrasting examples:

```
> library(Rmpfr)
  > K = 1:5
    > denoms = c(as.bigz(1), as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K) )
    #Big Rational ('bigq') object of length 6:
    #[1] 1   1   1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5
    > foo = c(1, as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K) )
    
    # [1] 1 5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    # [39] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0    

    > bar <- c(as.bigz(1), as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K) )
    
    #Big Rational ('bigq') object of length 6:
    # [1] 1   1   1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5
```

I understand that the method `c.bigq` may be incomplete, leading to failure of the desired interpretation and coercion of data types.  My question is: how did some `bigq` objects get turned into those vectors of 1s and 0s ?   The output  `foo` is numeric.

Comment: @parfait apologies, will add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dispatch on `c()` is done based on the class of the first element, so `c(1, as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K) )` calls the default method.

The second parameter `as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K)` has class `"bigq"`, but that's irrelevant, because the default method ignores the class. It just looks at the type, and `typeof(as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K))` gives `"raw"`, so it's stored as raw bytes.  If you call `unclass()` on it, you'll see something like

```
 [1] 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00
[40] 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
attr(,"denominator")
 [1] 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00
[40] 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00
```

so that's where all those numbers came from.

On the other hand, `c(as.bigz(1), as.bigq(rep(1,times = length(K)), K) )` has a `bigz` object as the first argument, so it will call `c.bigz`.  That method knows about `bigz` and `bigq` objects and does the right thing with them.

Comment: Ahh, of course, the good old "dispatch order" thing.  Thanks for unfreezing my brain.